# What is the origin of 'cash'?

Tags: etymology, british-english, subcontinental-english

What is the etymology of 'cash'? According to the OED when it is used in 'cash-box' it descends from the French 'casse', and presumably Italian 'cassa'. However the word meaning 'loose change' is from the Tamil word 'kasu'. The question arises as to whether English used 'cash' before they began to have dealings with southern India?

Comment: Etymonline notes: Not related to (but influencing the form of) the colonial British _cash_ "Indian monetary system, Chinese coin, etc.," which is from Tamil _kasu,_ Sanskrit _karsha,_ Sinhalese _kasi._ – That is, _cash_ meaning money influenced a more specific _cash_ meaning certain kinds of Asian money, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 5):

OED shows various citations for *cash* as "coin, money" between 1590 and 1600.

> 1593   G. Peele *Famous Chron. King Edward the First* sig. H,   Now the Frier is out of cash fiue Nobles, God knowes how he shall come into cash againe.
>   1596   T. Nashe *Haue with you to Saffron-Walden* sig. O2v,   He put his hand in his pocket but..not to pluck out anie cash.
>   1600   Shakespeare *Henry V* ii. i. 110   *Nim.* I shall haue my noble? *Pist.* In cash most truly paid.

The [East India Company](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_India_Company) was granted a Royal Charter in 1600, but three ships had sailed to India in 1591, presumably returning within twelve or eighteen months.

OED's first citations do not indicate the word was in use with this meaning prior to the ships' return.

Comment: The first two meanings in the OED are given separate etymologies. The second one cites the Tamil word as the origin. But the first one cites the French 'casse' as the origin of cash-box. I think this is either an error or a misprint. I'm sure the French word they are thinking of is 'caisse', which is variously used in French for cash-desk, as a prefix for a bank e.g Caisse d'Epagne (Savings bank) etc. I admit that I had always assumed that the French 'caisse' and our 'cash' came from the same root. But now it seems fairly evident that they don't.

Comment: French *casse* is English *chest, strongbox* isn't it?

Comment: I'm not at home and hence do not have my French dictionary with me. But the verb 'casser' means to break, or smash. In the on-line dictionary I've located, all the derivations relate to breakage of some kind.

Comment: We're not talking Modern French, necessarily. OED has "*cash*  < French *casse* ‘a box, case, chest, to carrie or kepe wares in, also a Marchants cash or counter’ (Cotgrave)..."

Comment: I looked this up in a Harraps' French to English dictionary this evening. Clearly the spelling 'casse' is archaic and obsolete. One of the meanings under 'caisse', the fourth one listed, is 'cash'. Its main usage is for a locked box or chest, or for a cash desk such as in a hotel, or savings bank etc. Thus it would seem to me that the English etymology is clearly Tamil. But what has probably happened is that the French 'caisse' has acquired an additional meaning of 'cash' because of the English word. Having said that, I have never heard a French person use 'caisse' for 'cash'.

Answer (score 5):

I think OP's original instinct, that *cash* and *caisse* are cognate, was right. *Casse* or *chasse* (from L. *capsa*) appears to have been the usual [French spelling](http://atilf.atilf.fr/scripts/dmfX.exe?IDF=dmfXgXpcYrmXcYbbi;ISIS=isis_dmf2012.txt;MENU=menu_dmf;OUVRIR_MENU=2;s=s11042838;LANGUE=FR;FERMER;AFFICHAGE=2;MENU=menu_dmf;;XMODE=STELLa;FERMER;;) (and, presumably, pronunciation) in the 14th C, and the word entered [English](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED6890) at the same time. In both languages it had the general meaning “box, coffer”.

At the end of the 16th century it appears to have attained a European currency [sic!] in  the additional narrower sense—derived, I suspect, from the merchant’s cash-*box*—of “cash-desk, till”. We find this in Florio's 1598 *A Worlde of Wordes, Or Most Copious and exact Dictionarie in Italian and English*:

[image: Florio]

And this in Randle Cotgrave's 1611 *A Dictionarie of the French and English Tongues*:

[image]

In these definitions I take it that *counter* has  *OED 1*’s *Obs.* meaning 3. “A table or desk for counting money, keeping accounts, etc.”.  (*OED* 4. is clearly derivative, but not attested until 1688 “A banker’s or money-changer’s table; also, the table in a shop on which the money paid by purchasers is counted out, and across which goods are delivered.”)

Cotgrave, moreover, not only recognizes *caisse* as an alternative French spelling, he provides a French parallel to the English usage (*Prov.* I suppose to mean “Proverb” rather than “Provençal”):

[image]

(By the way—*cashier* in this sense is derived from Fr. *casser* “break, annul”, and refers to breaking up a company of troops, not to paying them off.)

Occam's Razor suggests that there is no need to look to derivation of *cash* from an Oriental term which according to *OED 1* is attested for this period only in the Port. spelling *Caixa*—which was itself a [falsely-friendly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend) application of the Portuguese cognate of *casse/cassa < capsa*.

Comment: I am not sure what the conclusion is to the interesting material you present, above. Does this mean that the Tamil etymology is relevant or not?

Comment: @WS2 ***I*** think it shows it to be irrelevant. 1) The English, French, Italian and Portuguese terms are all unambiguously cognate. 2) They shared a common money-box/money-table sense at the very time *cash* emerges in English. 3) The same pun is possible in English and French. 4) The Tamil term was introduced into Europe by borrowing but identified with the pre-existing Portuguese cognate due to its accidental phonological identity. I conclude that English *cash* is the local version and application of an international business term.

Comment: Perhaps reinforced by the Tamil term?  I've lived in France and I've never heard anyone use 'caisse' to mean cash. They speak of 'argent liquide', and of 'espèces'. It is interesting that English is the only European language of those under consideration above, which clearly calls its note and coin 'cash', sounding like the Tamil.

Comment: @WS2 Modern Portuguese dictionaries tell me *orçamento de caixa* is "cash budget" and *fluxo de caixa* is "cash flow"; of course that may be under English influence. ... You may be right about reinforcement from Tamil. But when I find that "cash" used of values in nobles and pounds in the 1590s and hundreds of thousands of pounds by 1624; and then consider that the Indian coin was according to a source in Hobson-Jobson 1/733 of a noble, I suspect the influence went the other way, as H-J and OED state See Brad Szonye's Comment to OP. *Cash* meant, not small change, but ready money.

Comment: Clearly the OED have at some point been convinced that the Tamil word played an important part, as they name it as the etymology  of the principal meaning of 'cash'.

Comment: @WS2 I have only only *OED 1* and its *Supplements*, but they clearly distinguish *sb.1* meaning Money-box > money > specie from  *sb.2* , coin of low value in East Indies and China; Tamil and Sanskrit are cited only in the etymologies of the latter.

Comment: My experience of using the OED is probably negligible compared to your own, but what it seems to be telling me is that the Portuguese  'caixa' influenced various oriental peoples, and the word has come back to English as 'cash'.  The Portuguese had significant settlements throughout the Orient, including heavy influence in south India, and Sri Lanka, from the early 16th century. the British only began to arrive in the very late 16th and not in sizable numbers 'till the 18th.

Comment: My read would be that the British adopted/adapted the term to their existing *cash* meaning ready money, and extended it to other E.Asian coins of negligible worth--most those of China. That's the only context I ever recall encountering it in; the tiny Indian coin I remember from the fiction I read as a boy is the *pice*.

Comment: You will be interested in @jaydayb's answer, which provides further valuable insight, albeit originating from the humble Wikipedia. It seems the Latin derives from the Persian *karsha*.

Answer (score 4):

CASH , "Etymology
The English word cash is ultimately rooted in the Old Persian karsha meaning “a unit of value equivalent to one cash coin” and was first employed during the reign of Cyrus II followed by the establishment of the “formal” banking system and around the same time of the establishment of the credit and checking unions during the reign of Darius I who also minted the first face-coins.This form along with this meaning entered into the Sanskrit language during the post-Vedic era and also entered into Latin giving forms such as capsa “money box” (cf. OPers. Kshatrapavan = Satrap “an ancient Persian commercial and state confinement”) and case eventually passing into Middle French as caisse meaning “money in hand, coin...." source wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cash

Comment: Very useful post. Interesting that English *cash* and French *caisse* are both rooted in the Persian *kassa*. And it seems the French came via Latin - presumably. But the really interesting thing would be to know how it got into English. Was it from the Normans? That seems unlikely -see @Andrew Leach's answer. But you have added some very helpful further material on this, albeit with Wikipedia's help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a couple of years late here but I've always assumed CASH was derived thusly: CAISSE was and is the French word for a teller-window, a case or frame within which the bank employee would sit and transact money exchanges while the customer stood before it. Think of any old movie where a bank featured this elaborate wooden structure with metal bars. That employee was called the CAISSIER. Borrowed into English, he became CASHIER. And what would a CASHIER handle? CASH. I don't have authority for this explanation but it makes sense to me.